# how can i get the elementor error 1 of 4 resolved in the errors logs ? (playwrite python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, playwright

my code

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
from playwright.sync_api import expect

def run(playwright):
    chromium = playwright.chromium # or "firefox" or "webkit".
    browser = chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("https://www.hltv.org/stats/teams/ftu?startDate=2023-03-05&endDate=2023-06-05&maps=de_inferno&rankingFilter=Top30")
    # other actions...
    page.click('#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonLevelOptinAllowAll')
    
    find_results = page.locator('tr:has-text("Vitality")')

    n = find_results.inner_text()
    # confirm the number of elements/tags again
    print(n)
    

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
        run(playwright)
```

**ERRORS** *how can i get the element 1 of 4 = ("row", name="EuropeVitality 4 59.3% 48.4% 0.89 84.1% 36.2% 23.2% 40.1 0.22")*

[image: ERROR LOG]

Answer (score 0):

To select the first element, you can use [first()](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-locator#locator-first):

```py
page.locator('tr:has-text("Vitality")').first()
```

Alternatively, you can use the more generic [nth(0)](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-locator#locator-nth) to select first element:

```py
page.locator('tr:has-text("Vitality")').nth(0)
```